# UIWebView loadHTMLString in swift 4 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

Tags: ios, swift, ios11.2

I am getting below error when loading html string in webview

NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
I am not getting this error in iOS 9.3, only getting in iOS 11.2.

> webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL:nil)

Comment: `-1002` is `NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL`.

Comment: Can you share a [small reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of `htmlString`? I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am also getting this error, any update on this??